# ProGuard keep class name but change package name

Tags: java, proguard

want to change package name but need keep Class Name not change. any idea?

Comment: yes, idea: something wrong in your config file

Comment: The question should've not get downvoted, I didn't find anything simple to explain this that suits for beginners.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

ProGuard doesn't have a standard option to rename packages yet keep their simple class names.

You could create a ProGuard mapping file manually, with lines like:

```
com.example.MyClass -> a.MyClass:
com.example.MyOtherClass -> a.MyOtherClass:
```

You can then use the option `-applymapping mapping.txt`