# How to obfuscate only package names using Proguard

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I want to rename only package name in my application from com.**company1**.utils --> com.**company2**.utils.

How to do this using ProGuard? I Don't want to apply any optimizations in this except changing my package names.

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard doesn't have a standard option to rename packages, yet keep their simple class names.

You could create a ProGuard mapping file manually, with lines like:

```
com.example.MyClass -> a.MyClass:
com.example.MyOtherClass -> a.MyOtherClass:
```

also with this command: `-applymapping mapping.txt`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792982/4960200

Answer (score 0):

This might be totally weird, but since your package name is "utils" and we faced a similar issue on our project https://github.com/coding-blocks/CBOnlineApp, I can tell you that renaming our package from `utils` to `util` solved the proguard issue that it removes the entire package.

This needs deeper digging, but maybe some internal configuration problem leads proguard to remove packages named "utils"