# proguard applymapping - changes of mapping.txt doesn't applied on next build signed apk

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

i'm working on hardcoding obfuscation folder name using applymapping function from ProGuard, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15792982/10148104)

in this case, i'm obfuscating android project, so it's using gradle as the build tools

at first, it works as expected. using applymapping, i obfuscate file path `com.mycompany.SplashScreenPresenter` to `com.noWhereCompany.SplashScreenPresenter`

but... when i change mapping to a new path like `com.companyX.SplashScreenPresenter`, the signed apk i build was still using mapping of `com.noWhereCompany.SplashScreenPresenter`...

it's like when i build new signed apk, the gradle or proguard is still using old configuration..

i wonder what is the trigger to apply new changes in the mapping.txt. i tried build -> clean project but still no effect

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

okay i discovered the answer..

> i wonder what is the trigger to apply new changes in the mapping.txt.

one should add no-side-effect changes in `AndroidManifest.xml`, like adding comments or reorder some activity tags (as long as they're inside tag application), and then changes in `mapping.txt` applied

feel free to add other answers here